# Install mahout without hadoop and eclipse

Tags: solr, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have to use mahout in my project. I don't want  it to be installed on hadoop for now. and I have access to a Linux machine through putty. so I cannot use eclipse. can any one briefly guide me on this ? I am new to this technology. I have used Solr. I have to use mahout and make it integrate with solr.

pls do help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

export this variable 
 MAHOUT _LOCAL= TRUE

Comment: Can you please tell me in detail ? I am totally new to this.
Thanks